# IntValue ?? 0 == -1? "-": "+" What does this mean?

Tags: swift, ternary-operator

I am importing price information and adding + or -.

I put the title code in print () and it works but I do not know what it means.

```
print("\(IntValue ?? 0 == -1 ? "-" : "+")")
```

Please explain it briefly to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The variable `IntValue` is an optional, which means its either an Integer or `nil`. `IntValue ?? 0` means that if `IntValue` exists, then use the value of `IntValue`. If `IntValue` is `nil`, then use the value 0. Next, compare that value with -1. If that value is equal to -1, then print `-`. If that value does not equal -1, then print `+`.

Here's equivalent code with only if statements:

```
var defaultInt = 0
if IntValue != nil {
    defaultInt = IntValue! // force unwrap the optional value
}
if defaultInt == -1 {
    print("-")
}
else {
    print("+")
}
```

Comment: I think it should be `if IntValue != nil` as you only want to use the value of `IntValue` if it’s not `nil`; otherwise use `0`

Comment: War10ck is right. That line should be `if IntValue != nil`

Answer (score 10):

Kevin's answer is very good.

Some background that helps explain further:

The code you posted uses two rather cryptic operators together.

`??` is the nil-coalescing operator.

It takes an optional value, which can contain nil, and provides a new value to use when it **does** contain nil.

---

### Edit:

(Note that you can skip the nil-coalescing operator and use `IntValue == -1` instead. That works because only a non-nil value of `-1` is equal to `-1`. An optional that contains nil is not equal to `-1`.

You could rewrite the line as

```
print("\(IntValue == -1 ? "-" : "+")")
```

And get the same result.)

---

The next tricky bit is the "ternary operator". This comes from C. It's quite cryptic, but also quite useful.

It takes the form `boolean` ? `value_for_true` : `value_for_false`

Where `boolean` is a boolean expression that evaluates to `true` or `false`.

If `boolean` is true, then the result of the whole ternary expression is the `value_for_true` sub-expression.

If `boolean` is false the result of the whole ternary expression is the `value_for_false` sub-expression.

`IntValue ?? 0 == -1` is the boolean part of your ternary expression. It evaluates as true if IntValue is -1. It evaluates as false if IntValue contains any other value, or if it contains nil.

(Note that variables and let constants should start with lower-case letters, so `IntValue` should be `intValue`.)